# How to stop a view in RecyclerView from updating its value when it has focus?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a set of `CardView` that contain an `EditText` in each card. The `RecyclerView` adapter receives a list of numbers every second and it binds the data to each CardView's EditText.

However, when the user click on one of the `EditView` I want that `EditView` to stop changing every second while the `EditView` has the focus, so the user can enter their own data.

I don't really know what to do `if (editView.hasFocus)`

---

**Adapter**

```
class ConverterRecyclerViewAdapter(val ratesList: ArrayList<Currency>,
                                   val context: Context?,
                                   val onRateListener: OnRateListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ConverterRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View, val onRateListener: OnRateListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{

        var editText: EditText
        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_conv_cv)
        }

        fun bindItem(currency : Currency){
            itemView.currency_name_conv_cv.text = currency.currencyName
            itemView.country_currency_name_conv_cv.text = currency.countryCurrencyName
            itemView.value_conv_cv.text = SpannableStringBuilder(currency.value.toString())
            itemView.flag_iv_conv_cv.setImageResource(currency.flag)
            itemView.tag = currency.currencyName
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onRateListener.onRateClick(adapterPosition, itemView.currency_name_conv_cv.text.toString())
        }
    }

    interface OnRateListener {
        fun onRateClick(position : Int, currency : String)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.converter_card_layout, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view, onRateListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ratesList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItem(ratesList[position])
    }
}
```

**CardView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag_iv_conv_cv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currency_name_conv_cv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CURRENCY"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_tv_padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/list_item_tv_padding"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag_iv_conv_cv"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/flag_iv_conv_cv"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_currency_name_conv_cv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag_iv_conv_cv"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/flag_iv_conv_cv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/currency_name_conv_cv"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/list_item_tv_padding"
            android:text="Country Currency Name"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value_conv_cv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/country_currency_name_conv_cv"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="100"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Fragment**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ConverterViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.initialisePositions()
        viewModel.setupTimer(viewModel.ratesPositions[0])

        val ratesLiveData = viewModel.rates
        ratesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { data ->
            refreshData(data.rates)
            viewModel.sortListByPositionsArray(ratesArray)

            val firstElementInRecyclerView = viewModel.ratesPositions[0]
            val view = recyclerView.findViewWithTag<View>(firstElementInRecyclerView)
            lateinit var editText : EditText

            if (converterAdapter == null) setUpRecyclerView()
            else {
                converterAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Posting some code would help.

Comment: @MohamedHamza hi Mohamed, what part of the code would you want me to post?

Comment: paste the adapter code.

Comment: @JoseGarcia XML of the card item and the adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you want to update your item when you don't have the focus on it, so indeed you have to use `if (!editView.hasFocus()) {}`

Then if you have to check if your list `ratesArray` is holding the same items or not, because if you do `ratesArray.clear()` at some point, you're clearing the objects then the `RecyclerView` will create a new `ViewHolder` for your item.

If you are clearing and creating new objects continuously, you have to "pair" your Adapter with the items.

For example, if you always clear the items and create them again respecting the position, add this method to your Adapter:

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}
```

you can relate the "rate" in any other ways (a `String` inside the object, for example). If you do it with the `position`, you're pairing each item with their order.

Now, to finish "respecting that order", you have to tell the adapter that it has stable ids. That's done with `Adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe like this:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if(!holder.editText.hasFocus()){
    holder.bindItem(ratesList[position])
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

remove the focusable attribute for edittext and add this to its xml

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in the adapter:

```
 //decalare clicked item as member of the class and set it to -1

 var clickedItem = -1;

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if(clickedItem != position){
    holder.bindItem(ratesList[position])

     }

    //on click
     holder.editText.setOnClickListener {

       clickedItem = position;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

}
```

Comment: Did you make the editText focusable to true in the xml of the recyclerview item?

Comment: no luck mate :( it was true by default anyways. I appreciate your help

Comment: I guess it has to do with the fact that the view is already bound to the view holder and when I get the updates I call notifyDataSetChanged() and I guess that method that doesn't re-bind the views

Comment: try my update, I am not kotlin developer but when you read you get what I mean.

Comment: Hey Hasan, that update didn't work. i tried with and without notifyDataSetChanged() and no luck again. This is very strange :(

Comment: I added the code for the fragment. Maybe the issue is in the way i am observing the livedata?

Answer (score 1):

Your EditText needs special binding so remove this line from fun bindItem():

```
itemView.value_conv_cv.text = SpannableStringBuilder(currency.value.toString())
```

And on onBindViewHolder, bind this view only when it's not focused, which requires listening. Try this:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = ratesList[position]
    holder.bindItem(current)
    holder.value_conv_cv.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            holder.value_conv_cv.text = SpannableStringBuilder(current.value.toString())

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look in here? http://www.github.com/josegbel/rev-example

Comment: Your code made some items to show data and others not to show anything. Nonetheless even when focused, the view kept refreshing with new data

Comment: I added the code for the fragment. Maybe the issue is in the way i am observing the livedata?

Comment: Commit your last version of it, I'll have a look tomorrow.